# entry widget and label is not worling when i use grid(). But when i use pack() label is printing

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
 root=Tk()


 lab1=Label(root,text="Restaurant Management System")
 lab1.config(font=("Courier", 44))
 lab1.pack(side=TOP)
 lab2=Label(root,text="Meals")
 e2=Entry(root)
 lab2.grid(row=0)
 e2.grid(row=0,column=1)
 root.mainloop()
```

both entry and label widget is not coming in the console when i use grid().But when i use pack() it appears.What is the reason? Im using python 3.7

Comment: You can't mix `pack` and `grid` with widgets that have a common parent.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably avoid using `grid` and `pack` in the same tk container.

```
import tkinter as tk

if __name__ == '__main__':

    root = tk.Tk()

    lab1 = tk.Label(root, text="Restaurant Management System")
    lab1.config(font=("Courier", 44))
    lab1.grid(row=0, columnspan=2)
    lab2 = tk.Label(root, text="Meals")
    e2 = tk.Entry(root)

    lab2.grid(row=1, column=0)
    e2.grid(row=1, column=1)

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: what does the if statement mean? @Reblochon